# Creating a reference to dereferenced pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I recently looked at some code, and someone used this:

```
void Foo(vector<vector<int>>* arr_ptr){
vector<vector<int>>& arr = *arr_ptr;
//use arr
}
```

Is there a purpose to create a reference to a dereferenced pointer? As long as the pointer isn't null, couldn't the same result be performed using just this:

```
void Foo(vector<vector<int>>& arr) {
//use arr
}
```

Comment: Indeed it looks like ideally they should modify the function to just take a reference. But maybe there's some other design constraint (is it a virtual function perhaps?), or a legacy habit, or just plain sloppiness.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish: Or it needs to be this way to interface with other code not under the author's control ("legacy habit" minus the "habit").

Comment: @TheUndeadFish: Maintaining the integrity of your code's interface is hardly "sloppy".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Which would probably fit more into the other categories I mentioned. And that's fine. But I've also seen more than enough code which uses pointers for no good reason at all, so I included that as an option as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wouldn't be the the same to the code *calling* this method.

In the original code, the argument would be a pointer to type *X*; in your version, it would be of type *X*.

Comment: A short explanation might be in order.

Comment: If I initialize a vector<vector<int>> and call this code using the first way, and then the second way, wouldn't the result be the same? The only difference is the way I call it?

Comment: @shawtynerd Yes. The exception being if Foo shared the pointer to another part of your application.

Comment: The way you call it is kind of important to those who need to, you know, call it.